# Base Class for multiple viewmodels

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

Out of sheer necessity I am having to add two viewmodels to an activity and need to make a base class to do so, It is a half baked project I need to work on. I am trying to make a generic class to instantiate a viewbinding object and multiple viewmodels(in this senario 2) in the Base Class but I am stuck at the `get`method of the `ViewModelProvider` function where the get is not accepting the class type. Please help.

```
abstract class BaseActivity<B : ViewBinding, VM : ViewModel>(val bindingFactory: (LayoutInflater) -> B,
                                                            private val vMClass: List<Class<VM>>) : AppCompatActivity() {

    protected val binding: B by lazy { bindingFactory(layoutInflater) }
    var viewModel : ArrayList<VM> = arrayListOf()
   
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        for(i in vMClass.indices){
     /** error here -> */        viewModel.add( ViewModelProvider(this@BaseActivity).get<ViewModel>(vMClass[i]))
            
        }

        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

Comment: having two ViewModel is not a problem but why are you using a List to hold/Create them ? I would advise keep a single VM in BaseActivity and if you need a second VM better create it inside the concrete Activity itself.

Comment: to supply the viewmodel classes.....how would you do it if you had to ?

Comment: This is I am asked to do and I have no idea how to go about it

Comment: Recommendation(s) in no particular order. 1. Don't use a base activity for stuff that by convention is "two lines of code". 2. Why do you need two viewmodels in a single activity? Why not use a viewmodel and correctly inject the different behaviors (like interactors, use-cases)? Why are you _so hard_ trying to break the convention and go against the framework?

Comment: I've had a need for 2 VMs actually before, but I do agree that the BaseActivity to create a BaseVM etc etc is generally not a good idea.

Comment: ok guys I will look into the correct way of doing it.